# Probability density function of thermodynamical variables in statistical mechanics

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

How can we, in statistical mechanics, compute the probability density function of a thermodynamical variable?

I'll make a concrete example:

Let's consider a Fermi gas. Usually, in statistical mechanics we can quickly obtain the mean pressure of the gas, but how can we obtain the entire probability density function of the pressure?
In other words, if I measure the pressure of the gas thousands and thousands of times and I make a histogram, what will be the shape of that histogram?

Statistical mechanics is not my subject of study (I study particle physics), but this question grips me since my second year of university.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a macroscopic variable expressed in terms of microstates - considering for simplicity classical case:
$$
f(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q})
$$
whereas the thermodynamic distribution is defined by a probability density function like
$$
w(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q}) = Z^{-1}\delta\left(H(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q})-E\right)\textrm{ (microcanonical)},\\
w(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q}) = Z^{-1}\exp\left(-\beta H(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q})\right)\textrm{ (canonical)}.
$$
Then the average of the variable is calculated as
$$
\langle f(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q})\rangle = \int d^N\mathbf{p}d^N\mathbf{q} f(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q})w(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q}),
$$
its n-th moment by
$$
\langle \left[f(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q})\right]^n\rangle = \int d^N\mathbf{p}d^N\mathbf{q} \left[f(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q})\right]^nw(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q}),
$$
its probability distribution by
$$
w_f(F)=\langle \delta \left[F-f(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q})\right]\rangle = \int d^N\mathbf{p}d^N\mathbf{q} \delta \left[F-f(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q})\right]w(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q}),
$$
where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta-function.

One could now do calculations for the distribution of the pressure of an ideal gas.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways of obtaining probability distribution functions in SM:

1. *Using different ensembles:* The canonical ensemble allows the exchange of energy with a reservoir in thermal equilibrium, and the distribution of energies can be derived:
   $$ P(E)=Z^{-1} \Omega(E) e^{-\beta E}.$$
   Allowing the exchange of particles with a reservoir in chemical equilibrium one access the grand-canonical ensemble and the joint distribution of energy and number of particles:
   $$ P(E,N)=\Xi^{-1} \Omega(E,N) e^{\mu N-\beta E}.$$
   Note that the distribution of particles is the marginal of the above distribution:
   $$ P(N)=\sum_E P(E,N).$$
   Similarly, if you are interested in the distribution of Valumes, then you have to work in the [Isobaric ensemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isothermal%E2%80%93isobaric_ensemble), that allows exchange of volumes at constant pressure,
   $$ P(E,V)=\Xi^{-1} \Omega(E,V) e^{-\beta P V-\beta E}.$$
2. *Change of variables:* Taking the classical limit in which energies are continuous, the canonical ensemble gives you the probability density function for the energy:
   $$P(E)=Z^{-1} g(E) e^{-\beta E}. \quad\quad (1).$$
   Thanks to the Hamiltonian, we can evaluate the (macroscopic) energy of the system from the knowledge of the microscopic system (position and momentum for all particles):
   $$E=H_N(\{\vec{q}_i,\vec{p}_i\}_{i=1,\dots,N})$$
   The above equation can be inserted in (1) to obtain the probability distribution function of microstates:
   $$P(\{\vec{q}_i,\vec{p}_i\}_{i=1,\dots,N})=Z^{-1}\frac{e^{-\beta H_N(\{\vec{q}_i,\vec{p}_i\}_{i=1,\dots,N})}}{h^{3N}}.$$
   Now if you can express a macroscopic variable (say $F$) as a function of the microscopic variables ($F=F(\{\vec{q}_i,\vec{p}_i\}_{i=1,\dots,N})$) or as a function of the energy ($F=F(E)$), you can access the probability distribution as a change of variables:$$P(F)=Z^{-1} J(F/\vec{q},\vec{p})e^{-\beta H_N(F)}=Z^{-1} J(F/E)e^{-\beta E(F)}.$$